# How to retrieving a list object in the entity?

Tags: list, one-to-many, google-cloud-datastore

I have an entity that has a List object.  I can see the object that currently contain one element.  However, when I tried to retrieve the list, I always get null.

There are three classes: two entity classes and an endpoint class

```
public class Buddy{
...
    @Persistent (mappedBy="owner")
    @Order (extensions = @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus",key="list-ordering", value="sharedOn desc"))
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Sticky>    listOfObjects;
...

    public List<Sticky> getStickies(){
       return listOfObjects;
    }
}

public Class Sticky{
...
    @Persistent (dependent="true")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Buddy owner;
...
    public Buddy getBuddy(){
       return this.owner;
    }
...
}


public class StickyEndpoint{
...

@ApiMethod(name = "createSticky")
public Sticky createSticky(Sticky sticky){
    Buddy buddy = sticky.getBuddy();            // confirmed that buddy returned is not null
    List<Sticky> sticky = buddy.getStickies();  //sticky always return null
    ...
    return sticky;
}

....

}
```

Can someone help?  Thanks!

Comment: please provide the code for the whole class. so we can see how the entity is being stored/retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDO will not let u insert custom type, so List will not run.  I ended up installing Objectify....